# Pass a variable to a form using Symfony 1.4 and Propel

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, propel

I need to pass a variable from an action class to a form using Symfony 1.4 and Propel.

I have tried the method listed here: [Pass a variable to a Symfony Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853830/pass-a-variable-to-a-symfony-form)
which I believe is a method that works with Doctrine, but not Propel.

This is what I've tried:

action class:

```
$this->saved_cart_form = new ItemSavedCartForm(array(), array('user_id' => $user_id));
```

form (line to grab variable):

```
$this->getOption('user_id');
```

This hasn't worked, and there isn't much documentaion, but I believe you need to pass options through the forms constructor function, which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a constructor to the form and passing the variable to it through the action.

Action:

```
$this->saved_cart_form = new ItemSavedCartForm($this->getUser()->getUserId());
```

Form:

```
class ItemSavedCartForm extends myFormHorizontal
{

    protected $user_id = null;


    public function __construct($user_id = null)
    {
    $this->user_id = $user_id;

    parent::__construct();

    //rest of class...
}
```

Afterwards, `$this->user_id` is available throughout the form class. If anyone can find documentation or articles about other ways to do this through Symfony 1.4 and Propel, please share - I'd be very interested to see other solutions.

Comment: Works for me...Cheers